Save diff from Magit
Sometimes I want to create a diff file from within Magit and send it to someone else, just like I do with git diff > /tmp/a.diff. Can I do that in Magit?

There is a different command, magit-patch, for this.  The command only works in a Magit Diff buffer. So, you have to do:

magit-diff-unstaged (C-c d) or similar command to create a "Magit Diff" buffer
magit-patch-save or W s in the "Magit Diff" buffer
Select a file to write

Also, if you want to copy the diff to kill-ring or buffer, you can do the following. This is taken from https://github.com/magit/magit/issues/4462
;; ** Magit
(use-package magit
  :defer
  :config
  (require 'magit-patch)
  (transient-insert-suffix
    'magit-patch "r" '("b" "Save diff as patch to buffer" my/magit-write-patch-to-buffer))
  (transient-insert-suffix
    'magit-patch "r" '("w" "Copy diff as patch to kill-ring" my/magit-copy-patch-kill-ring))
  )

;; Taken from https://github.com/magit/magit/issues/4462
(defun my/magit-write-patch (write-function &optional arg)
  "Write patch of current diff to a temp buffer, then run WRITE-FUNCTION.

This is useful as a backend abstraction for
`my/magit-write-patch-to-buffer' and `my/magit-copy-patch-kill-ring'.

Cribs lots of code from `magit-patch-save'. Inspired by
https://github.com/magit/magit/issues/4462#issuecomment-892358920."
  (interactive)
  (require 'magit-mode)
  (require 'magit-diff)
  (unless (derived-mode-p 'magit-diff-mode)
    (user-error "Only diff buffers can be saved as patches"))
  (let ((rev     magit-buffer-range)
        (typearg magit-buffer-typearg)
        (args    magit-buffer-diff-args)
        (files   magit-buffer-diff-files))
    (cond ((eq magit-patch-save-arguments 'buffer)
           (when arg
             (setq args nil)))
          ((eq (car-safe magit-patch-save-arguments) 'exclude)
           (unless arg
             (setq args (-difference args (cdr magit-patch-save-arguments)))))
          ((not arg)
           (setq args magit-patch-save-arguments)))
    (with-temp-buffer
      (magit-git-insert "diff" rev "-p" typearg args "--" files)
      (funcall write-function)))
  (magit-refresh))

(defun my/magit-write-patch-to-buffer (buffer)
  "Write patch format of current diff into chosen buffer.

Finishes with chosen buffer displayed. Uses `magit-patch-save'
internally, so inherits its settings."
  (interactive (list (ivy-read "Dump/append patch to buffer: " #'internal-complete-buffer
                   :def "*patch*")))
  (my/magit-write-patch '(lambda () (append-to-buffer buffer (point-min) (point-max))
               (pop-to-buffer buffer))))

(defun my/magit-copy-patch-kill-ring ()
  "Copy patch format of current diff into kill ring.

Uses `magit-patch-save' internally, so inherit it's settings."
  (interactive)
  (my/magit-write-patch '(lambda () (kill-region (point-min) (point-max)))))

